# Spring AOP: aspect is not executing in case of MethodConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, spring-aop

I have a bean annoteded with JSR 303 annotations. I also added Spring aspect (@Around) for handling MethodConstraintViolationException. My problem is: if I execute methods with correct parameters - my aspect works (is executed - breakpoints added), but when I run methods with incorrect parameters then MethodConstraintViolationException is thrown and my aspect is not executed.

```
package noname.exception;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;

import noname.service.exceptions.ValidationException;
import noname.utils.ValidationExceptionProcessor;

@Aspect
public class ExceptionAspect implements Ordered {

    @Autowired
    private ValidationExceptionProcessor processor;

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* noname.conversionstrategy.api.IDocumentConverter.*(..))")
    public void aopDocumentConverterPointcut() {
    }

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* noname.service.api.IMailMerger.*(..))")
    public void aopMailMargeServicePointcut() {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Around("aopDocumentConverterPointcut() || aopMailMargeServicePointcut()")
    public Object exceptionsAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch ( Throwable e ) {
            if (e instanceof MethodConstraintViolationException) {
                ValidationException exp = processor.process((MethodConstraintViolationException) e);
                throw exp;
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

Intefaces (IMailMerger and IDocumentConverter) are similar:

```
package noname.conversionstrategy.api;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import noname.service.domain.DocumentActionInput;
import noname.service.domain.DocumentActionResult;
import noname.validator.ValidActionInput;


@Validated
public interface IDocumentConverter {

    DocumentActionResult convertDocument(@NotNull(message = "DocumentActionInput must be provided") @ValidActionInput DocumentActionInput document);

    List<DocumentActionResult> convertDocuments(@NotNull(message = "DocumentActionInput must be provided") @ValidActionInput List<DocumentActionInput> documents);

}
```

I suppose spring execute first bean validation (it is probably executed with aspect too (?) ). If this validation throws MethodConstraintViolationException then my aspect is not executed, because spring aop doesn't support catching exceptions from anoother aspect (need confirmation).

I also created test with proxy (everything with my aspect looks fine):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContextTest.xml"})
public class ExceptionAspectSpringTest {

    @Autowired
    private IDocumentConverter documentConverter;

    @Autowired
    private ExceptionAspect exceptionAspect;

    private IDocumentConverter proxy;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        AspectJProxyFactory aspectJProxyFactory = new AspectJProxyFactory(documentConverter);
        aspectJProxyFactory.addInterface(IDocumentConverter.class);
        aspectJProxyFactory.addAspect(exceptionAspect);
        proxy = aspectJProxyFactory.getProxy();
    }

    @Test( expected = ValidationException.class )
    public void shouldThownValidationException() {
        DocumentActionInput document = new DocumentActionInput();

        proxy.convertDocument(document);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Can you show us the methods you want to be advising? I'd also like to see your pointcuts.

Comment: Post edited (pointcuts and intefaces added)

Comment: I can't really reproduce this as I don't know what validation your are using, but you should be able to simply debug the code and see which path the invocation on the proxy is taking.